# Hive error: cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.serde2.RegexSerde

Tags: hive, hive-serde

I am very new here, I am trying to run the following code on my 
[cloudera quickstart VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkltV.png).

```
CREATE TABLE apache_common_log (
  host STRING,
  identity STRING,
  user STRING,
  time STRING,
  request STRING,
  status STRING,
  size STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
```

`"input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"`
   `[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)",`
  `"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s"`
  `)
   STORED AS TEXTFILE;`

but I got some error:

```
failed: execution error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask, Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerde
```

I did some research, all the fields are STRING, and i have add jar 
`/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib.jar`
`/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serde.jar`
`/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common.jar`

it still didn't work. 
really need some help!
any input will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please replace the picture with a textual code. Use ctrl+k to format it.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark but try using single-quotes instead of double-quotes inside the SERDEPROPERTIES() body with no spacing between the keys, the equals signs, and the values.  I don't think you need 'STORED AS TEXTFILE' either.

Comment: sorry , very new, still trying to figure out how to quote the code:(

Comment: And I tried to use single-quotes instead of double-quotes, still got the same error @PaulBack

Comment: Thanks!!I've figured it out, keep double-quotes only for "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s", and it works!